# Show uniform convergence of Picard-iterates

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $$y'(x) = xy(x) + x^3 \qquad y(0) = 0$$ and let $y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denote its global solution. Determine $t_0 > 0$ such that the recursive sequence of functions $$y_0(x) \equiv 0 \qquad y_{n + 1} := \int_0^x \left( ty_n(t) + t^3\right)dt$$ converges uniformly on $[-t_0,t_0]$

I have a problem with this exercise, since I do not explicitly know $y$ (can be calculated, but I think this should not be used here). Can someone give me a good starting point?

Comment: Consider the function space $C([-t_0,t_0])$ with the norm $\|f\| = sup|f(x)|$ for $x\in [-t_0,t_0]$. Try to prove contraction mapping on this function space i.e. try to prove $\|y_{n+1}- y_{n}\| \leq C \|y_{n}- y_{n-1}\|$ for a constant $C<1$. This gaurantees uniform convergence on $[-t_0,t_0]$. You should get that any $0<t_0<\sqrt{2}$ should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind Picard-iteration is the Banach fixed-point theorem which states: Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and $\Phi: X\rightarrow X$. Then $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point provided $\Phi$ is a contraction mapping, i.e. there exists $0<C<1$ such that $d(\Phi(u), \Phi(v)) \leq Cd(u, v)$.

We shall apply the fixed-point theorem to show the iterated sequence defined by
\begin{align}
y_{n+1}(t) = \int^t_0 (sy_n(s) + s^3)\ ds
\end{align}
converges uniformly to some function, say $y(t)$, on some interval $[-t_0, t_0]$ for some $t_0$.

To use the fixed-point theorem, we need to first select an appropriate metric space $X$. Let us choose the space $X=C([-t_0, t_0]\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$, which denote the space of real-valued continuous function on $[-t_0, t_0]$, where $t_0$ is yet to be determined. It's clear that $C([-t_0, t_0]\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ is a complete metric space with respect the supremum metric $||\cdot ||_\infty$. Now, let us define the map $\Phi$ on $X$, by
\begin{align}
\Phi(u)(t) = \int^t_0 (s u(s)+ s^3)\ ds.
\end{align} 
The natural question is the ask whether $\Phi$ maps back to itself, which it does since an anti-derivative of a continuous function is continuous. Then we want to know whether $\Phi$ is a contraction to guarantee the existence of a fixed point. Observe
\begin{align}
||\Phi(u)-\Phi(v)||_X =& \ \sup_{t \in [-t_0, t_0]} \left|\int^t_0 s(u(s)-v(s)) \ ds\right| \leq \sup_{t \in [-t_0, t_0]}\left|\int^t_0 |s||u(s)-v(s)|ds \right|\\
\leq &\ \sup_{t \in [-t_0, t_0]}\left[ \sup_{s \in [-t, t]}|u(s)-v(s)| \frac{|t|^2}{2} \right] \leq \frac{|t_0|^2}{2}|| u-v||_X
\end{align}
which is a contraction if $|t_0|<\sqrt{2}$. Thus, by the fixed-point theorem, it follows $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point and the sequence defined by $\{\Phi^n(y_0)= y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to the fixed point in $X$. Since $\{y_n\}$ converges in $C[-t_0, t_0]$ which has the uniform metric on $[-t_0, t_0]$, then it follows $y_n$ converges uniformly on $[-t_0, t_0]$ (of course provided $t_0<\sqrt{2}$).